# Querying an embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have a Bson with some embeddeds documents following the structure below. I'd like to know how to get, for example, the value of a variable ("2014-08-09": 53.0) or the value of an inventory ("2014-08-09": 0.0) on a specific date.

```
{
    "_id" : ,
    "last_modified" : "",
    "client" : "",
    "credentials" : [],
    "tags" : [],
    "variables" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "sales",
            "_values" : {
                "2014-08-09" : 53.0,
                ...
            },
            "tags" : [],
            "is_target" : true,
            "method1" : "",
            "method2" : "",
            "vtype" : ,
            "index_type" : 
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "inventory",
            "_values" : {
                "2014-08-09" : 0.0,
                ...
            },
            "tags" : [],
            "is_target" : ,
            "method1" : "",
            "method2" : "",
            "vtype" : ,
            "index_type" : 
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "_values" : {},
            "tags" : [],
            "is_target" : ,
            "method2" : "",
            "method1" : "",
            "vtype" : ,
            "index_type" : 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mongodb aggregate framework
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

```
db.mycol.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$variables"},
    {$project:{"date":"$variables._values.2014-08-09"}}
])
```